# adding a sequence to an existing table

Tags: oracle, constraints, oracle-apex, primary-key

i created a table but i forgot to add a sequence to one of the PK, its a sequence on a form page, i just cant find anything about it, is it possible or do i have to do the form all over again.
i tried to replace the PK but it doesnt give me the option to add the sequence when creating a new one.
i searched everywhere and asked the support in chat (didn't really help since its not their job).
all i could find was [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/aeutl/managing-sequences.html#GUID-E177ACD2-7FCD-4536-974B-62D7E84576C3) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/aeutl/managing-tables.html#GUID-B21034CD-D55E-47DF-9042-237C5F98A369).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to **skip Apex** in this matter and do the following: presume this is your table:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id     number constraint pk_test primary key,
  3     name   varchar2(20)
  4    );

Table created.
```

This is the sequence:

```
SQL> create sequence myseq;

Sequence created.
```

As you forgot to specify PK source while creating Apex Form page, never mind - let the database handle it. How? Create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_test
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4    when (new.id is null)
  5  begin
  6    :new.id := myseq.nextval;
  7  end trg_bi_test;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Let's test it: I'm inserting only the `NAME` (which is what your Apex Form will be doing):

```
SQL> insert into test (name) values ('Littlefoot');

1 row created.
```

What is table's contents?

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Littlefoot

SQL>
```

See? Trigger automatically inserted ID (primary key) column value.

If it were an Interactive Grid (which lets you insert several records at a time):

```
SQL> insert into test (name)
  2    select 'Bigfoot' from dual union all
  3    select 'FAD'     from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Littlefoot
         2 Bigfoot
         3 FAD

SQL>
```

Works just fine.

And what's another benefit: you don't have to modify Apex application at all.

Comment: thank you but I HAVE to use apex, i was doing some school project and i just found out its something i shouldve done a couple of months ago so i dont know if i have to start all my work since may. i know how to do it with just sql but i cant find a way to do it through apex or if there is anyother way

Comment: If it has to be in Apex, then create a process which populates the primary key item with a sequence value, e.g. `:P1_ID := myseq.nextval;` which runs when CREATE button is pressed.

Comment: thank you, i should do it in SQL WORKSHOP>SQL SCRIPTS right?

Comment: Do what? Create a trigger? Yes, in SQL Workshop's "Commands". If you're asking about creating a process, then it is in App. Builder, Page Designer, Processing pane.